# OpenСvSharp 4. Наложение изображений

Tags: c#, opencv

Использую OpenCvSharp 4. Возникла такая проблема. 
Необходимо наложить одно изображение (меньшее) на большее (фактически - фон) с указанием позиции меньшего изображения по X и по Y (то есть сделать тоже самое, что сделало бы e.Graphics.DrawImage).

_matCanvas.Rectangle(<положение и размеры меньшего>) - рисует прямоугольник правильно и там, где необходимо.

А вот "врисовать" одно изображение в другое не получается никак. Пробовал и smallImage.CopyTo(_matCanvas[область])  и _matCanvas[область] = smallImage и все прочее. Насколько я понимаю, _matCanvas[область] - возвращает новый Mat, а не отрисовывает что-то в указанной области.

Не подскажите, как все-таки нарисовать одну картинку поверх другой (фона) с указанием позиции по X и по Y?

Answer (score 0):

Конкретно по `c#` не подскажу, но в `c++` это так делается:

```cpp
cv::Mat origImage = cv::imread("some_image", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);
cv::Mat imageForInsert = cv::imread("other_image", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

cv::Rect rectForInsert{cv::Point{100, 100}, imageForInsert.size()};
cv::Mat roi = origImage(rectForInsert);
rectForInsert.copyTo(roi);
```

Думаю по аналогии найдете в документации